# intercept redis message when using nestjs cmd pattern

Tags: javascript, redis, nestjs

hello guys i have nestjs code that emit and recieve data in redis and it works perfectly

```
@Controller('healthz')
// @Injectable()
export class AppController {
  constructor(@Inject('TEST_SERVICE') protected client: ClientProxy) {}
  
  @Get('/test')
  @Public()
  async test() {
    const pattern = { cmd: 'your-command' };
    const data = { message: 'your-data' };

    // Send message and wait for reply
    const reply = await this.client.send<any>(pattern, data).toPromise();
    console.log('reply', reply); // Log the reply
  }

  @MessagePattern({ cmd: 'your-command' })
  async yourCommandHandler(data: any) {
    // Handle your-command message
    console.log('rec', data);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));

    return 'reply';
  }
}
```

now my problem is i want to know how to listen to that message in `redis cli` and i tried this

```
# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> SUBSCRIBE your-command
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "subscribe"
2) "your-command"
3) (integer) 1

127.0.0.1:6379> PSUBSCRIBE your-command
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "psubscribe"
2) "your-command"
3) (integer) 1
```

listening the way i did above did not work

Comment: Try using the command: `'"cmd":"your-command"'`